# Is my wiring to subpanel adequate?

Tags: wiring, subpanel

Here’s where I am at.  I have a metal shop building about 160 feet from my main panel.  I have a 400 amp service.  I ran 2 inch pvc conduit about 36” deep.  My wire is 3 wire 2awg use 2 aluminum with a 6ga insulated copper ground wire to the shop.  At the panel I also ran an 8 foot ground rod with a bare copper wire to the subpanel ground. I am set up with a 60 amp breaker on the house panel. The shop has a couple 20 and 15 amp breakers and will likely run a 40amp breaker for a welder or plasma cutter.  I don’t want to tear it all up again if I did something wrong but I’m not opposed to sizing the load down if I have to.

Comment: You need a disconnect at the shop building - either a separate disconnect switch or a main breaker. 60A in house protects the wire, so if you use a main breaker in the subpanel it can be any size 60A or larger. Also need either breaker/GFCI or receptacle/GFCI for all the 20A and 15A circuits.

Comment: The USE-2 is 3 real separately insulated wires, NOT 2 real wires and an over-braid 3rd conductor?

Comment: I should have added that the sub panel is a 100 amp square d with 100 amp main breaker.  Do I need to install a gfci still?   Do all my outlets need a gfci breaker?  Thanks

Comment: You need GFCI protection. You don't need a GFCI breaker, other than for a 240V receptacle. The GFCI can be the first thing in line on the circuit. and will protect the rest of the outlets if wired correctly. Please verify the type of USE-2, since it comes in different styles, and which style matters, here.

Comment: The 100A main breaker in the subpanel takes care of the disconnect requirement. You still need GFCI, either on the individual breakers or on the receptacles. My recommendation is on the receptacles - saves a bit of $. Note that with NEC 2020 (gradually rolling out across the country) you will need GFCI even on the welder circuit!

Comment: The ground rod is at the shop.  If 2 awg aluminum is not up to 60 amps at 160 feet what is the max safe amperage I should run to the shop? 

The wire says 2 awg al type use-2 60 mils xlp 600 volts. There are six strands of aluminum wire If that makes any difference

Comment: There is some question regarding running that size **cable** through conduit. But the wire size is good. Use individual 2 awg al wires instead of cable and then everything is just right.

Comment: @MarkWie I'm trying to establish if you installed the cable style that is 2+ ground, (which can't be a neutral) or if the cable has an acceptable neutral conductor. USE-2 cables are made both ways. You described it as 3 wire and now you've described it as 6 strand. [Edit] in a picture of the end of the cable and that will clear things up.

Comment: Can’t figure out how to add a pic. I’m sorry it is 3 individual aluminum wires with a hard insulation each wire has strands as in not a solid piece of aluminum.  They are two black and one black with a yellow stripe which i used as the neutral.

Comment: Good to go, then!

Answer (score 1):

### You did just about right, actually.

Ground rods, fat conduit, #2 aluminum which is approved for 90A in this circumstance (as feeder panel-panel).

There's no worries on voltage drop. You are only allowed to *plan to* load the #2 feeder to 80% of ampacity, so 72A. Given 160' and 240V power, your voltage drop would be 2.82% which is more than adequate.  ("3%" is mostly a wire salesman's lie).

The only real risk here is getting too small a subpanel, thus painting yourself into a corner later and having to do a costly re-do.  Breaker spaces are cheap and 90A wire can power *a lot of stuff*.

The subpanel does not need a main breaker.  It needs a main disconnect near the point where the power enters the building, but - if the subpanel is there, a disconnect can be part of it.  That is why you see people use main-breaker subpanels, they are using the main as a disconnect switch (for which it is more than qualified).